# Django Form doesn't validate when I add a prefix

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a form that I needed to add a prefix to run some javascript. The problem is that the form won't validate. I have set all fields to required = false and tried saving the form, but it still doesn't validate.

Any idea why this is happening?

As an example form 1) validates, but form 2) does not:

1) `AddClassForm()`
2) `AddClassForm(prefix="add")`

Comment: Show the code of your view, please.

Comment: while validating, are you sending the prefix correctly? Example `AddClassForm(request.POST, prefix="add")`

Comment: @karthikr that was the issue, thanks! I wasn't aware that you also have to send the prefix during validation.